# cat file.pyz | python fails, why?

Tags: python, encoding, terminal, file-encodings

I want to execute a `pyz` file over SSH in this way:

`cat test.pyz | ssh -M user@somehost python`

This is the current output:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    PKimport sys
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

After some digging, I discovered that if I try:  `cat test.pyz | python` OR `python < test.pyz` on my terminal I get the same error message.

If I try this: `python test.pyz`  Python successfully executes the bundle. Sadly, this is not an option for me.

Any ideas why and how to  successfully run my pyz bundle (*in the cat | python fashion*)?

ps. The `pyz` file prints "Hello World" --that's it

Comment: Is this supposed to be an executable zip archive? You can't run those from stdin.

Comment: It's true that the file has the "PKImport sys" at the start. But Python doesn't complain if I execute the pyz file in this way: "python test.pyz". Question edited to reflect this update.

Comment: zipapps do not work over stdin

Comment: `python test.pyz` and `cat test.pyz | python` are very different things. The first one tells python "hey, here's this file name, run it". The second one says "here's this long stream of text, run that".

Second option is not supported for zipapp.